# Linker error when use Json to parse the string

Tags: objective-c, json

I am trying to use JSON to parse the sting that i have got from ASIHttpRequest but i find linker error e.g.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
```

Below is the code that i am using.For more detail i have already added Json classes in the project.

```
(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init ];
    NSDictionary *obj=[parser objectWithString:responseString error:NULL];
    NSArray *list=[obj objectForKey:@"lessons"];
    // Use when fetching binary data
   //  NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}
```

Comment: dasblinkenlight is correct of course. :) BUT this seems to be me like it would be good time to switch to NSJSONSerialization ! [Either patch ASI or better yet: move away from it!]

Answer (score 0):

From the search i found that we have to include the .m Json files in the compile source. We can do this by click on the project->Target->Build Phase->compile source->add the all the json .m files